# matrix similar to diagonal matrix and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n,n}$  is similar to some diagonal matrix $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$.  $P_M$ means characteristic polynomial for matrix $M$.
Then:
a. $P_A$ is a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $n$.
b.  $P_A$ is product factors degree's one
c.  $P_A=P_D$

I know that similar matrix have the same characteristic polynomial.
Because $D$ is diagonal and real then each eigenvalue is real.  Hence,
a. true
b. true
c. true

Am I ok ?

Comment: Did you correctly quote the claims? Because b isn't proper grammar. But yes, $P_A$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and a product of linear polynomials. No, $P_A$ does not (in general) have degree $1$.

Comment: why should "a" be true?

Comment: Why ? After all, polynomial for diagonal matrix is product product factors degree's one.  In "a" I edited my post.

Comment: After edition all answers should be ok ?

Comment: b is false because you can have some factor of kind $(X-a)^p$